# The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context (SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2012, web-parts

i have visual studio 2012 SP1 ,and i am using visual web part  and i am having { The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context } and the "ascx.g.cs" file is not filled. but it does not disappear as it happeneds in VS 2010

I know there is a lot of links about it but i tried the most of them and it seems now its something with VS 2012.

I tried the following

1) install VS 2012 SP1

2) my contents length below visual studio 2010 limitation of  8256 characters main is (3399  with spaces)

4) restart VS / Restart PC.

5) I am only referencing  a SharePoint custom WCF services

**the wired thing is this.**

i created a new visual webpart , and copy past the content without the CSS link. every thing worked fine. but when i added the CSS link. i got the same building error.

here is the link css code

```
<link href='<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TaskModuleCSS" Text="    <%$Resources:TMS.UI,TaskModuleCSS%>"/>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

so i remove it , but that did not remove the error.

Any idea , i stucked here and begin to think to remove the VS2012 and rebuild my solution in VS 2010. :/

Comment: I tried to replace the <%$Resources:TMS.UI,TaskModuleCSS%> with a text , and also no luck ,, but when i change the literal by URL , its worked ,, i always use this in my SharePoint projects why its not working in Visual Studio 2012 !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry for late replay ,, no i did not , but i was opening the solution in VS 2010 add the webpart , then reopen the solution in vs2012 ,, last week a new update for visual studio came , i will try it and see if the issue has been resolved..
did you find any ?Q

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this error by Running Custom Tool on .ascx files for every form (web part) in the solution:

1. Right click on SomeForm.ascx file
2. Run Custom Tool

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Designer file for your webpart or not. I have also faced the same issue, but in my case, webpart.ascx.g.cs file was missing.

Comment: the file is exist ,,, its really weird

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that a lot of people is having this issue ,, 
its seems this issue is not related to specific thing ,,, it can be one of the following

1. the site URL in the SharePoint project property is not valid [ This happens when you copy past the solution from one environment to another ]
2. You have HTML tag error in you Design view (ex missing closing tag)
3. Missing designer files just like @hir said.
4. sometime using Resource files do this problem, so I work around it by develop the web part without any resource then generating it by the VS.

I am using now VS 2013 ,, I only face this issue for points 1 to 3